# Entity Framework 1-1..1 relationship not functioning as expected

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

So basically I have a Student Table that holds a required foreign key to a Person table. I have set up my classes as follows:

```
class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Phone_Number { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Last_Name + ", " + First_Name;
    }
}

class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int Student_TypeID { get; set; }

    //navigation properties
    [Required]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I attempt to add a new student as below, the foreign key to person remains at 0:

```
Student student = new Student
{
    Dob = dpStudentDob.Value,
    Student_TypeID = (rdoStudentRegular.Checked) ? 1 : 2,
    Person = new Person
    {
        First_Name = txtStudentFirstName.Text,
        Last_Name = txtStudentLastName.Text,
        Address = txtStudentAddress.Text,
        Email = txtStudentEmail.Text,
        Phone_Number = txtStudentPhoneNum.Text
    }
};

using (var context = new MusicSchoolDB())
{
    context.Students.Add(student);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

No matter how many times I add a student, the foreign key to person remains at 0. . .

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: Additionally, when viewing the database diagram in SSMS, the relationship has formed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of EF code first is to name your foreign key in this way: `Person_ID`. You called your property `PersonID`, so EF does not realize this is supposed to be your foreign key. Internally in your database there is a column created named `Person_ID` which is just not mapped in your model.

Using the data annotations you can explicit tell EF what your foreign key property is:

```
public int PersonID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("PersonID")]
public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
```

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj679962 the convention for a foreign key does not include an underscore?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class Student
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        [Key]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public int Student_TypeID { get; set; }

        //navigation properties
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }

class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Phone_Number { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }

        //navigation properties
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Last_Name + ", " + First_Name;
        }
    }
```